# How can I reliably get status information from a running Snakemake workflow?

Tags: workflow, snakemake

Snakemake is great but I'm having difficulty getting status information on running workflows reliably. For example, the --summary argument complains that the directory is locked due to a running process, which is true, but spits out the info anyway, which is good. But maybe I'm just getting lucky and in future versions it will refuse to give me information just like the --detailed-summary errors?

What I'm trying to do is to integrate Snakemake into my application, the workflows have many rules and each rule can take a long time. Many workflows will be executed simultaneously and so I'm looking for a programmatic  way to query the status. The best I can think of is to use the --wms-monitor capability but rather than use panoptes, write my own server. Is this the best way to go?

Comment: I don't know of any other solution, but why don't you want to use panoptes? Do you need more features?